# What's the most lightweight way to do this with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, menu

I've got a simple menubar with a hover effect:

http://www.bridgecitymedical.com/

Now, I'm adding sub-menus. I'd like (on hover of one tab), a div slides down with all the sub options inside for that corresponding div. I'm wordpress, so displaying the contents is as easy as using a built-in function, but what's the best way to go about the drop down effect?

Here's a picture of what I intend:

[image]

I figured I could create a div that size nested in each tab, then use jQuery to animate its dimensions outward like this:

```
$('.menu').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).animate ... etc
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).animate ... etc
  }
);
```

But I would end up with a lot of silly divs around, wouldn't be very clean. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it have to animate vertically and horizontally at the same time?

Comment: No, one at a time. The first page slides down (shown as first black arrow), then the second page slides right, then the third slides right, then the fourth, all in a quick animation. A bit complex? I've tried it, but it always ends up really messy-looking and doesn't degrade nicely.

Comment: And if the mouse is moved diagonally? (I hate it when a badly designed menu forces me to move the mouse in awkward angled paths....)

Comment: What do you mean "diagonally"? Why would that change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way is very simple and effective.

```
var speed = 130; // milliseconds
$('.menu li').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).find('div').slideDown(speed);
}, function(e) {
    $(this).find('div').slideUp(speed);
});
```

If you want it to slide down *and* over at the same time, then you can use `show()` and `hide()` instead and it will automagically do that for you.

**Edit:**
For your div that pops down try adding margin-left equal to the width of the logo image.

**Edit 2:**
Careful with putting the div outside of the `ul` because now when you try to hover over the div it triggers the mouseleave (`blur`) event and causes the div to slide back up.

Try this is a workaround (or something to that effect):

```
var divEntered = false, open, close;
var closeFunction = function() {
    $('.sti-subitem').slideUp(150, function() {
        // set closed flag
    });
};
$('.sti-menu').hover(function() {
    $('.sti-subitem').slideDown(200);
}, function() {
    close = setTimeout(closeFunction, 600);
});

$('.sti-subitem').mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(close);
});

$('.sti-subitem').mouseleave(function() {
    close = setTimeout(closeFunction, 600);
});
```

Comment: That would make the tabs themselves slide up and down, right? Where does that second row of sub-items come into your snippet?

Comment: Good point, sorry I was typing super fast hehe. I changed it now. Try that.

Comment: what is function (e) for? Why not function ()?

Comment: ahh because it passes the event object too.. so you can do things like `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent event bubbling and what not. http://snipplr.com/view/2810/stop-event-propagation-stop-an-event-from-bubbling-up/

Comment: Sweet. But I need some css styling to go with. I applied your technique:

Comment: dang. the menu isn't showing up at all for me. :S the CSS part is gonna be much more tricky..I would have to get my hands dirty to get that... Maybe try `.yourMenuDivClass { position: absolute; margin-top: /* height of menu */; }`.. something like that maybe

Comment: My thought precisely. Trying now.

Comment: I've added a border too it, and added a top margin. But it's not showing up. :/

Comment: The submenu is called ".sti-subitem" and its in the unordered list

Comment: Great. now you don't need the margin-top part anymore.. it appears wherever you moved it just giving it position: absolute give it the right vertical position. now read my edit and try adding the margin-left to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4819/discussion-between-jackson-gariety-and-mmmshuddup)

Comment: It worked dude! This snippet you posted here... the one with timeouts. Changes the two 600's to 0. ^_^

This snippet is different form the one you posted in chat.